# SimpleXML IF condition

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an XML document that will either return a URL or an error code. If it returns an error code I'd like to redirect the page to an error image. I can get SimpleXML to return the URL, but I am not sure how to write a condition if the error returns. If anyone has any suggestions, that'd be great! This is what I have right now:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$url = 'http://radiocast.co/art/api1/key=KeyHere&album=' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["album"]) . '&artist=' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["artist"]) . '';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$img = $xml->xpath('//image[@size="large"]');

$large = (string)$img[0];

header("Location:".urldecode($large));

?>
```

This is what the XML document returns if it cannot be found:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lookup status="failed">
<error code="3">Art not found</error></lookup>
```

Comment: tip 1: rename the variable to `$lookup` after the name of the root element. improves readability. tip 2: http_build_url or sprintf is nicer for building the url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about checking for the error node in your XML, and if you find it then handling the various errors? If you don't find it you can continue with your normal logic.

```
if (isset($xml->error)) {
    switch ($xml->error['code']) {
        case '3':
            // not found stuff here
            break;

        // other error codes here
    }
} else {
    // success logic here
    $img = $xml->xpath('//image[@size="large"]');
    $large = (string) $img[0];
    header("Location: " . urldecode($large));
}
```

Comment: I'm getting several warnings and a fatal error. I'm still not sure what to do

Comment: The errors are your friends :-) work out which lines they coincide with, and Google the error message if you don't know what the error is referring to. If you can't solve them yourself, and you can't find anything on Google, post your problem back here!